# Check in component is null in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have a Angular 8 application. But I get this error: on a component. And it is a component in a component. And if a component is empty then the error will be shown if the component is not null then the error will not be shown

```
:4200/dossier-dossier-module-ngfactory.js:186 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of null
    at DossierCorrespondenceItemComponent.push../src/app/dossier/dossier-correspondence-item/dossier-correspondence-item.component.ts.DossierCorrespondenceItemComponent.ngOnInit (:4200/dossier-dossier-module-ngfactory.js:100)
    at checkAndUpdateDirectiveInline (vendor.js:37850)
    at checkAndUpdateNodeInline (vendor.js:46063)
    at checkAndUpdateNode (vendor.js:46025)
    at debugCheckAndUpdateNode (vendor.js:46659)
    at debugCheckDirectivesFn (vendor.js:46619)
    at Object.updateDirectives (:4200/dossier-dossier-module-ngfactory.js:189)
    at Object.debugUpdateDirectives [as updateDirectives] (vendor.js:46611)
    at checkAndUpdateView (vendor.js:46007)
    at callViewAction (vendor.js:46248)
```

on this component:

```
  <app-dossier-correspondence-item
    [item]="single"
    (goBack)="goBack($event)"
    *ngIf="showingSingle">
  </app-dossier-correspondence-item>
</app-vital10-page>
```

this is the ts code:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { HealthAPIService } from '../../shared/health-api/health-api.service';

import { DossierEntry } from '../../interfaces/dossier/dossier-entry.interface';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-dossier-correspondence',
  templateUrl: './dossier-correspondence.component.html',
})

export class DossierCorrespondenceComponent implements OnInit {
  allCorrespondence: Array<DossierEntry>;
  correspondenceEntries: Array<DossierEntry>;
  attachmentEntries: Array<DossierEntry>;
  message = '';
  emptyMessage = 'Geen correspondentie.';
  errorMessage = 'Er ging iets mis met de connectie. Probeer over enkele minuten nogmaals.';

  correspondenceLoaded = false;
  showingSingle = false;

  single: DossierEntry;

  constructor(private healthAPIService: HealthAPIService) {}

  handleCorrespondenceLoad(result) {
    if (result.length === 0) {
      this.message = this.emptyMessage;
      return;
    }
    this.allCorrespondence = result;
    this.attachmentEntries = [];
    this.correspondenceEntries = [];
    for (let entry of result) {
      switch (entry.type) {
        case 'correspondence': {
          this.correspondenceEntries.push(entry);
          break;
        }
        case 'attachments': {
          this.attachmentEntries.push(entry);
          break;
        }
        default: {
          break;
        }
      }
    }
  }

  gotoItem(index, type: string) {
    this.showingSingle = true;
    // this.single = this.allCorrespondence[index];
    switch (type) {
      case 'correspondence': {
        this.single = this.correspondenceEntries[index];
        break;
      }
      case 'attachments': {
        this.single = this.attachmentEntries[index];
        break;
      }
      default: {
        break;
      }
    }
  }

  goBack(event) {
    this.showingSingle = false;
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.healthAPIService.getDossierEntry('correspondence').subscribe(result => {
     
      if(result){
      this.handleCorrespondenceLoad(result),
      (this.correspondenceLoaded = true);}
    }, msg => (this.message = this.errorMessage));
  }
}
```

So how to fix this? Thank you. So will be nice to solve this issue

This is the code of the DossierCorrespondenceItemComponent

```
ngOnInit() {

    if (!this.item.isJson) {
      if (window.btoa) {
        this.safeHTMLUrl = this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(
          'data:text/html;base64,' + btoa(this.item.summary)
        );
      } else {
        this.safeHTMLUrl = this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl('data:text/html;utf-8,' + this.item.summary);
      }
    }
  }

  openInNewTab() {
    const popup = window.open('', '_blank');
    popup.document.write(this.item.summary);
  }
```

You mean like this:

```
 handleCorrespondenceLoad(result) {



    if (result.length === 0) {
      this.message = this.emptyMessage;
      return;
    }

   
    this.allCorrespondence = result;
    this.attachmentEntries = [];
    this.correspondenceEntries = [];
    for (let entry of result) {
      switch (entry.type) {
        case 'correspondence': {
          this.correspondenceEntries.push(entry);
          break;
        }
        case 'attachments': {
          this.attachmentEntries.push(entry);
          break;
        }
        default: {
          break;
        }
      }
      this.showingSingle = true;
    }
  }
```

Comment: show the ts code

Comment: I edit the post

Comment: `handleCorrespondenceLoad()` should verify result is not null before starting to work with it.

Comment: Can you do a console.log and show us what are the contents of `results`?

Comment: Shouldn't there be a semicolon after `this.handleCorrespondenceLoad(result)`?

Comment: results are:[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object]

Comment: The element is enabled when you set `showingSingle` to `true` within `gotoItem`. But in the moment you enable it your `single`is not yet set. Please set `showingSingle` to `true` AFTER your switchcase.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The element is enabled when you set showingSingle to true within gotoItem. But in the moment you enable it your singleis not yet set. Please set showingSingle to true AFTER your switchcase.

```
gotoItem(index, type: string) {

    // NOT HERE

    switch (type) {
      case 'correspondence': {
        this.single = this.correspondenceEntries[index];
        break;
      }
      case 'attachments': {
        this.single = this.attachmentEntries[index];
        break;
      }
      default: {
        break;
      }
    }

    this.showingSingle = true; // BUT HERE
  }
```